# Loading config files / handling errors on startup in a WPF/MVVM app

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, configuration, error-handling

*Disclaimer: I have no prior experience in MVVM/MVC/MVP/MVWhatever, this is my very first try using **any** UI separation pattern.*

On startup, my app needs to load data from a config file, which is needed for the application to work.

At the moment, I'm reading the config file on startup in `App.xaml.cs`, and I'm passing the content of the file to the view model:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        string configFile = "settings.txt";
        string[] config = File.ReadAllLines(configFile);

        var window = new MainWindow();
        var viewmodel = new MainWindowViewModel(config);
        window.DataContext = viewmodel;
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

**1. Is this the "correct" MVVM way?**
I'm sure that this way is better than reading the file directly in the view model (that's how I did it first), but I'm not sure if `App.xaml.cs` is the right place at all for reading config files.

**2. Where/how do I handle errors?**
The data from the config file is essential for the application.
So if the file is missing or empty, or if the data in the file is invalid, then I need to display an error message and quit the application.

My first attempt would be to put that in `App.xaml.cs` as well:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        string configFile = "settings.txt";

        if (!File.Exists(configFile))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("config file missing");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
            return;
        }

        string[] config = File.ReadAllLines(configFile);

        if (config.Count() == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("config file empty");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
            return;
        }

        var window = new MainWindow();
        var viewmodel = new MainWindowViewModel(config);
        window.DataContext = viewmodel;
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

But that doesn't look "right" to me. I already didn't feel comfortable with loading the file there (see first example), so this is even worse.

*Note: I know that I probably shouldn't directly call `Messagebox.Show` here.

Please note that this is **not** what I'm asking here - I know that I should replace it by something more MVVM-like, but the point is: I would still have to call that (and then close the app) from somewhere.

What I actually want to know is if `App.xaml.cs` is the right place for this!*

**3. Plus, I have another kind of error to handle:**
The actual parsing of the config file is done by the model *(the model is part of an existing library and the WPF app I'm building here is just a nice UI for that)*.
So the view model creates an instance of the model and calls the parsing method...which throws an exception if the data from the config file is invalid.

How do I handle this the "MVVM way"?
Just catching the exception in the view model and closing the whole application from there feels wrong to me.

---

**EDIT:**

To answer Will's comment about why I'm not using `app.config`:

I'm using a "special" configuration file because I need to load several named "sets" of value pairs from there. [Here's an example file](https://github.com/christianspecht/missilesharp/blob/master/src/MissileSharp.Demo/settings.txt).
Basically, it's a `Dictionary<string, List<ClassWithTwoStringProperties>>`.

1. AFAIK, `app.config` doesn't support data like this, so the only thing I could do is save the whole thing as a blob in **one** property in `app.config`, and still do the parsing myself.
   --> so I'd still have to call the parsing from somewhere in the WPF app.
2. I wanted a simple, human editable format
3. the WPF app is just a nice UI for a library, and I need a config file in the library as well

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use normal configuration settings?  App.Properties.Default.LikeThisOneEtc?

Comment: @Will: yes, there is. I just edited the question!

Comment: You can support this using custom configuration sections, but its really a pain in the ass to code them up, so I normally don't suggest people use them.  In other words, carry on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, this way is incorrect.

You should think about `app.config` as about any persisted data (e.g. database, file). If you want to access persisted data in MVVM way, you should write a service (something like `IApplicationDataService`) and call this service implementation from your `MainWindowViewModel` code. It will be more MVVMish, if you will locate this service from some `ServiceLocator` or inject it via IoC container - this helps to write unit tests later.

Implementation of service should return to view model initialized model instance. Something like this:

```
public ApplicationDataService : IApplicationDataService
{
  public ApplicationModel LoadApplicationData()
  {
      // process app.config here
  } 
}

public ViewModelBase<TModel>
{
  public TModel Model
  {
    get { return model.Value; }
  }
  private readonly Lazy<TModel> model = new Lazy(GetModel);

  protected abstract TModel GetModel();
}

public MainWindowViewModel<ApplicationModel> : ViewModelBase
{
   protected override ApplicationModel GetModel()
   {
      try
      {
        var dataService = ServiceLocator.GetService<IApplicationDataService>();
        return dataService.LoadApplicationData();
      }
      catch (AnyException e)
      {
         // oops!
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How would I handle the errors thrown by the data service? Do I call `MessageBox.Show();` and `Application.Current.Shutdown();` in the view model where I catch the exception? (the place where you just wrote `// oops!` in your example)

Comment: ...of course I'll replace `MessageBox.Show` by a `MsgBoxService` or something. But my actual question is: is the view model the right place for triggering error messages and shutting down the application?

Comment: @ChristianSpecht: yes, it's a right place. This what view models is intended for - to be a glue between different parts of application. Also, for non-critical errors you can hold an errors/warnings/messages collection and display them in the view via controls like `ValidationSummary`.

Comment: This doesn't work when the initialization logic of the `ServiceLocator` is determined by the app.config file, for example.